# On Solvability of an Equation with the Sigma Function

Tags: number-theory, diophantine-equations, divisor-sum

I have researched this question and need help.  In general is there only one solution to the equation $\sigma(nx) = (n+4)x$ for every $n$?  Specifically, is there only one solution to $\sigma(5x) = 9x$? ( I know x = 2 is a solution, but is there a way to prove that there are no more?)

Comment: I believe that this question is related to an open problem in elementary number theory - that of showing that $10$ is a [solitary number](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/SolitaryNumber.html).  However, that problem is still unsolved (see [Ward's](http://arxiv.org/abs/0806.1001) and [Kim's](http://ajmonline.org/ojs/index.php/AJM/article/viewFile/51/44) papers for some background on the current limits of knowledge that can be derived from existing theory and known facts.)

Comment: There is also a related paper by [Gachimu, et. al](http://journals.jkuat.ac.ke/index.php/jagst/article/view/789/721) that gives "necessary conditions for existence of a friend of the number $38$".

Comment: That is exactly at the heart of what I am trying to do.   Thank you for the comment and references.